# How do I override getting values from UserSecrets?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have implemented a basic EMailSender which looks a bit like this:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set via Secret Manager

    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {...}
    
    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {...}
}
```

Where the `AuthMessageSenderOptions` has these two properties:

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

This service is injected during `startup.cs` like so:

```
 // Adding EMail sender and authentication service
 services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
 services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

And I put my `SendKey` and `SendUser` values...

```
{
  "SendGridUser": "JamHeadArt",
  "SendGridKey": "MY-API-KEY-XYZ-ABC"
}
```

on my local dev machine in `C:\Users\JamHeadArt\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\aspnet-myAppName-GUIDGUIDGUID` in a `.json` using

```
dotnet user-secrets set SendGridKey MY-API-KEY-XYZ-ABC -p C:\Users\JamHeadArt\source\repos\myAppName\myAppName\myAppName.csproj
```

This all works great. My e-mail sender is populated with the values from the user secrets file (it's using `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`) and I'm successfully sending e-mails.

However, I'm not having any success populating the API key after publishing this app to live (publish to folder and drop in IIS on SQL Server 2016)

1. I tried just adding a `secrets.json` file following the same `%APPDATA%` path, using the same GUID file id but it doesn't work.
2. I tried adding my two values to the `appsettings.json` but still nothing:

   ```
   "Logging": {
       "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
       }
     },
     "ConnectionStrings": {
       "DefaultConnection": "wah wah!"
     },
     "AllowedHosts": "*",
     "SendGridUser": "JamHeadArtLIVE",
     "SendGridKey": "MY-API-LIVE-KEY"
   }
   ```

**How can I populate these `AuthMessageSenderOptions` properties on my live environment?** How can I get the service to pull these values from `appsettings.json`?

Comment: If you have these settings in ANY of the configuration providers that are loaded by the host builder it will work. If it doesn't work with appsettings.json then I think you added them incorrectly, like maybe nested under some other key. Can you show it, or at least the structure with fake values?

Comment: it's ASP.NET Core and yeah I'll add the appsettings structure now

Comment: @Crowcoder I added the `appsettings.json` as it is on live with subbed key and conn string. I assume there was no nesting needed and if there was, I had no idea what they'd come under (maybe AuthMessageSenderOptions ??)

Comment: That should work. Are you getting null values? I [have some code](https://github.com/crowcoder/IGAS_Workshop/blob/prod/Controllers/ConfigurationController.cs) that you can reference that will extract all config values and what provider they came from. It might help you debug. It will never work with user secrets because the host builder does not load user secrets in non-development environments.

Comment: Yup null value for ApiKey according to my error log. In retrospect I don't even need to use UserSecrets, I ended up just using a code snippet for the EMailSender that used it and now I'm thinking I'll rewrite.

Comment: User secrets is the right place for it (or at least a good place for it) during development so don't feel you need to put the values someplace that will get checked into source control. I'm not sure what your problem is but I'm confident it is NOT that you are using user secrets.

Comment: Seems like the other appsettings (e.g. appsettings.staging etc.) were affecting it. Got some weird stuff going on with my various appsettings. I'm manually removing all of them on publishing and just making sure my final, lone appsettings.json has the right conStr and apikey in it, then it works ok. Will figure out how to get this automated on publish sometime...